# Variable as object attributes in rails

Tags: ruby

I have two models(Customer, Product). They are associated with has_one relation. Currently I am doing this

```
@customer = Customer.first
@customer.product.name
```

This output, the name of the product and this works just fine. Now I want something like this

```
product_type = "product"
@customer = Customer.first
@customer."#{product_type}".name
```

This should output product name like before. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try  with types assuming `[:active, :sold, :not_active]` are the types of products

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :product
   [:active, :sold, :not_active].each do |type|
      define_method "#{type}" do
         product.where(type: type).first
      end
   end
end
```

Now `@customer.active.name` give  the active(type) product name

or `@customer.sold.name` give  the sold(type) product name

or  `@customer.not_active.name`give  the not active(type) product name

in this way you can define and call for all the other types as you need